# enable_if type is not of a certain template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sfinae, enable-if

TLDR: See the last paragraph.

I have an `operator&` defined for several template classes like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct Class {
    Class(T const &t) { }
};

template <typename T_Lhs, typename T_Rhs>
struct ClassAnd {
    ClassAnd(T_Lhs const &lhs, T_Rhs const &rhs) { }
};

template <typename T, typename T_Rhs>
ClassAnd<Class<T>, T_Rhs> operator&(Class<T> const &lhs, T_Rhs const &rhs) {
    return ClassAnd<Class<T>, T_Rhs>(lhs, rhs);
}

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T_Rhs>
ClassAnd<ClassAnd<T0, T1>, T_Rhs> operator&(ClassAnd<T0, T1> const &lhs, T_Rhs const &rhs) {
    return ClassAnd<ClassAnd<T0, T1>, T_Rhs>(lhs, rhs);
}

int main() {
    Class<int> a(42);
    Class<double> b(3.14);
    auto c = a & b;
}
```

This works just fine.

The problem occurs when I want to add a not operation, which is allowed on only one side or the other of an and operation, and must return an instance of `ClassAndNot` rather than `ClassAnd`:

```
template <typename T>
struct ClassNot {
    ClassNot(T const &t) : value(t) { }
    T value;
};

template <typename T_Lhs, typename T_Rhs>
struct ClassAndNot {
    ClassAndNot(T_Lhs const &lhs, T_Rhs const &rhs) { }
};

template <typename T_Lhs, typename T_Rhs>
ClassAndNot<T_Lhs, T_Rhs> operator&(T_Lhs const &lhs, ClassNot<T_Rhs> const &rhs) {
    return ClassAndNot<T_Lhs, T_Rhs>(lhs, rhs.value);
}

template <typename T_Rhs>
ClassNot<T> operator!(T_Rhs const &rhs) {
    return ClassNot<T_Rhs>(rhs);
}

...

auto c = a & !b;
```

This results in an ambiguity between the `operator&` taking an arbitrary right hand side to return a `ClassAnd`, and the `operator&` taking a `ClassNot` right hand side to return a `ClassAndNot`.

---

Question:

How could `std::enable_if` be used here to disable the first `operator&` if its right hand side is of any of the types `ClassNot`? Is there something like `std::is_same` that returns true if one side is a template instance of the other?

p.s. You can find a full working example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/wHlDZg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to construct your own trait for this:

```
template <class T>
struct IsClassNot : std::false_type
{};

template <class T>
struct IsClassNot<ClassNot<T>> : std::true_type
{};


template <typename T, typename T_Rhs>
typename std::enable_if<!IsClassNot<T_Rhs>::value,
ClassAnd<Class<T>, T_Rhs>>::type operator&(Class<T> const &lhs, T_Rhs const &rhs) {
    return ClassAnd<Class<T>, T_Rhs>(lhs, rhs);
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/JDT7kE)

---

Of course, you can go crazy with generalisations and create an all-purpose trait:

```
template <class T, template <class...> class TT>
struct is_instantiation_of : std::false_type
{};

template <template <class... > class TT, class... A>
struct is_instantiation_of<TT<A...>, TT> : std::true_type
{};

template <class T>
using IsClassNot = is_instantiation_of<T, ClassNot>;
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/stJqzO)

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I was looking for (but provided by the standard library). I'll go with the first example to keep things a bit simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @zennehoy I'd guess that one of the reasons it's not provided by the standard library is that there is no way to write it fully generally for class templates which take any non-type or template template parameters.