# template function which takes objects of type and objects of all derived types

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I want a template function which takes all objects which are instances of Base or any derived classes ( only one derived class here ) from Base. My following example did not work, see comments for what comes out and what I want to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base { };

template< typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> { };

//FIRST
template < typename T>
void Do( const T& )
{
    std::cout << "FIRST " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

// SECOND Should eat all types which derives from Base<T>
template < typename T>
void Do( Base<T>& base)
{
    std::cout << "SECOND " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    Derived<int> derived;
    Base<int> base;

    Do(base);       // SECOND void Do(Base<T>&) [with T = int]           OK
    Do(derived);    // FIRST void Do(const T&) [with T = Derived<int>]   Fail -> should go to SECOND!
    Do(1);          // FIRST void Do(const T&) [with T = int]            OK
}
```

The original code has `Base` as a template class. I simplified this but should be kept in mind.

I though about disabling the FIRST function with enable_if for base and derived types, but I could not find a idea for the correct trick. And also enabling the SECOND one only for the base and derived classes is a option, but I can't get the trick here.

I saw [enable_if type is not of a certain template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803679/enable-if-type-is-not-of-a-certain-template-class) but this is not helping with the derived ones.

EDIT:
Sorry, my given example was to much simplified. As given in the headline I need some template stuff to find out if the type of the template function is a instance of the template or derived from this template type. I modified the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a trait to check for classes that derive from any specialization of `Base`:

```
namespace detail {
    template<class T>
    std::true_type test(Base<T>*);
    std::false_type test(...);
}

template<class T>
struct is_derived_from_Base : decltype(detail::test((T*)nullptr)) {};
```

And use it to constrain the first function template:

```
template < typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_derived_from_Base<T>{}> >
void Do( const T& )
{   
    std::cout << "FIRST " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: OK, the tricky part I couldn't find was to get the T which is first a Base<T> and must split down for my T which is an int to be testet as Base<int>. Ok, I got it! Thanks!